# matDatepicker . matDatepickerFilter -> unable to select dates once an oldDate is typed in the date field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, mat-datepicker

I have a condition which should allow to select endDate which must be greater than equal to startDate. (Input can be either from calendar drop-down or manually typed).

Problem here is whenever I tried to enter the endDate that is prior to startDate, it throws error(has field validation as mentioned above) and then I try to select endDate from calendar drop-down, I see that all the dates in the calendar drop-down are disabled.
I would like to select date from calendar even though I've typed in an endDate prior to startDate without disabling the calendar dates.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

.html

```
 <input matInput #ref [matDatepicker]="this.enddate" [min]="minDate" [matDatepickerFilter]="endDateValidator.bind(this)" formControlName="commissionProgramEndDt"
                id="commprogram.commissionProgramEndDt" required>
```

.ts

```
    endDateValidator: (date: Date | null) => boolean = (date: Date | null) => {
    this.minDate = new Date (this.formatedStartDate);    
    this.result = new Date(this.formatedStartDate) <= new Date((this.formatedEndDate))
    return this.result;
   }
```

Comment: a custom formControl validator in ReactiveForm is a function that received the FormControl (really an AbstractControl), your "endDateValidator" is not a custom formControl validator, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators)

Comment: @Eliseo Can you please be precise on this?

Comment: sorry, I thougth you're using a customValidator. I suggest you use [`[min]` property](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepickerInput) in the second datepicker. I write a simple stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-an9ew1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html)